# How to install LLVM 3.9

Tags: software-installation, clang

I'm working with Emscripten and one of the error messages is:

```
LLVM version appears incorrect (seeing "3.3", expected "3.9")
```

But I can't find 3.9 on the LLVM page:

http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.8.0

What can I do to install LLVM 3.9?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Installing llvm 3.9 can easily be done under Xenial Xerus by using the 'LLVM Debian/Ubuntu nightly packages' PPA. Just follow the steps below:

1. Add the archive signature:

   ```
   wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Add the PPA:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.9 main"
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   **Note:** There may be some authentication warnings for the llvm key which I have safely overridden on my own system. To bypass authentication, replace `sudo apt-get update` with

   ```
   sudo apt -o Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories=true update
   ```
3. Allow the Repository to reload and then run the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install clang-3.9 lldb-3.9
   ```
4. Test your installation as follows, as shown on my own Xenial system:

   ```
   $ clang-3.9 --version
   clang version 3.9.0-svn275716-1~exp1 (trunk)
   Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
   Thread model: posix
   InstalledDir: /usr/bin
   ```

**References:**

- [LLVM Debian/Ubuntu nightly packages](http://apt.llvm.org/)

Comment: Is there any secure way for getting the key?

Comment: `https://apt.llvm.org` also works instead of `http://`

Answer (score 15):

Add following two lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file using `nano` or `vim` or any other your favorite text editor.

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main
```

Above lines are for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. If you are using Ubuntu 15.10, just replace `trusty` with `wily` in above lines. If you are using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, replace `trusty` with `xenial`.

Type following commands to install LLVM 3.9

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install clang-3.9 lldb-3.9
```

Answer (score 4):

Follow this official guidance http://apt.llvm.org/

e.g. for Ubuntu 14.04
Add following lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

`deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main`

To retrieve the archive signature:

`wget -O - http://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -`

Install stable branch

`apt-get install clang-3.9 lldb-3.9`